# Merging vectors of strings in a list in R

Tags: string, r, list, merge, match

I have a set of strings along with corresponding ID in ID:string format as a list of vectors in `R`

```
d <- list( c("SD1:LUSH", "SD44:CANCEL", "SD384:FR563", "SD32:TRUMPET"), c("SD23:SWITCH", "SD1:LUSH", "SD567:TREK"), c("SD42:CRAYON", "SD345:FOX", "SD183:WIRE"), c("SD345:HOLE", "SD340:DUST", "SD387:ROLL"), c("SD455:TOMATO", "SD39:MATURE"), c("SD12:PAINTING", "SD315:MONEY31", "SD387:SPRING"),  c("SD32:TRUMPET", "SD1:FIELD"))

[[1]]
[1] "SD1:LUSH"     "SD44:CANCEL"  "SD384:FR563"  "SD32:TRUMPET"

[[2]]
[2] "SD23:SWITCH" "SD1:LUSH"    "SD567:TREK" 

[[3]]
[3] "SD42:CRAYON" "SD345:FOX"   "SD183:WIRE" 

[[4]]
[4] "SD345:HOLE" "SD340:DUST" "SD387:ROLL"

[[5]]
[5] "SD455:TOMATO" "SD39:MATURE" 

[[6]]
[6] "SD12:PAINTING" "SD315:MONEY31"    "SD387:SPRING" 

[[7]]
[7] "SD32:TRUMPET" "SD1:FIELD"
```

I would like to merge the vectors by their IDs. Vectors having common IDs need to be merged while keeping their corresponding strings to form a new vector. Duplicate ID:String combinations can be removed within such merged strings. The total data contains around 2000 such vectors. The desired output from the sample data is

```
out <- c("SD1:LUSH, SD1:FIELD,  SD23:SWITCH, SD32:TRUMPET, SD44:CANCEL, SD384:FR563,  SD567:TREK", "SD12:PAINTING, SD42:CRAYON, SD183:WIRE, SD340:DUST SD345:FOX, SD345:HOLE, SD387:SPRING, SD387:ROLL", "SD455:TOMATO, SD39:MATURE") 

[1] "SD1:LUSH, SD1:FIELD,  SD23:SWITCH, SD32:TRUMPET, SD44:CANCEL, SD384:FR563,  SD567:TREK"            
[2] "SD12:PAINTING, SD42:CRAYON, SD183:WIRE, SD315:MONEY31, SD340:DUST SD345:FOX, SD345:HOLE, SD387:SPRING, SD387:ROLL"
[3] "SD455:TOMATO, SD39:MATURE"
```

I have tried converting it to a `data.frame` to use `merge()`, but found it not useful. Is it possible to first search for intersection using ID part of string followed by union of the corresponding vectors. I have tried using `intersect()` and `union()`, but I am failing to use only the ID portion of the vectors.

I am fairly new to writing R scripts.

**Update**
As @CarlWitthoft pointed out, I am trying to make the match condition for merging more clear with this image. [image: Match criteria]

In short I want to merge vectors that have an intersection between them in terms of SDxyz:___ or try to get the union of the overlapping string vectors.

## Solved it!!

Comment: You can split out the ID part with `lapply(d, strsplit, ":")` - but why SD1 and SD23 are in the first element of `out`, but SD12 is in the second is unclear from any properties of the data I can discern.

Comment: Vectors 1, 2 abd 7 should merge together as they has SD1 common between them. Vectors 3, 4 and 6 should merge as SD345  is common between 3 and 4 and SD387 is common between 4 and 5.

Comment: So you want all possible merges defined by the digits in `SDxyz` ?  Your 'desired output' does not appear to match any of your text descriptions of the "match criteria"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I want to merge all the vectors that have atleast one ID element in common between them. Vectors [1], [2] and [7] have **SD1:___** common between them. So they should merge together. Vectors [4] has **SD345:___** common with vector [3] and **SD387:___** common with vector [5]. So vector [4], [3] and [5] should merge together. Vector [7] is not having any element common with other vectors, so it should remain as such. Sometimes the same ID might be associated with multiple strings like SD1:LUSH and SD1:FIELD.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Vectors [1], [2] and [7] have **SD1:___** common between them. Also Vectors [1] and [7] have both **SD1:___** and **SD32___** common. So [1], [2] and [7] should merge together.

Answer (score 1):

#### Create a data.table Bloc with one column with original groups and the other with the separated ids

```
d <- list( c("SD1:LUSH", "SD44:CANCEL", "SD384:FR563", "SD32:TRUMPET"), c("SD23:SWITCH", "SD1:LUSH", "SD567:TREK"), c("SD42:CRAYON", "SD345:FOX", "SD183:WIRE"), c("SD345:HOLE", "SD340:DUST", "SD387:ROLL"), c("SD455:TOMATO", "SD39:MATURE"), c("SD12:PAINTING", "SD315:MONEY31", "SD387:SPRING"),  c("SD32:TRUMPET", "SD1:FIELD"))
d2 <-  lapply(d, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), "[", 1))

d <- lapply(d, paste0, collapse=", ")
d2 <- lapply(d2, paste0, collapse=", ")

d <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(lapply(d, paste0, collapse=", ")))
d2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(lapply(d2, paste0, collapse=", ")))

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(d,d2))
colnames(d) <- c("sdw", "sd")
d$sd <- as.character(d$sd)
d$sdw <- as.character(d$sdw)

require(data.table)

Bloc <- data.table( d , key = "sd" )
```

#### Fetch all the ids along with the corresponding data in Bloc

```
Bloc <- Bloc[ , list( ID = unlist( strsplit( sd , "," ) ) ) , by = list(sdw, sd) ]
Bloc$ID <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", Bloc$ID)
Bloc <- data.table( Bloc , key = "ID" )
```

#### Loop to merge the vectors having ids intersecting between them

```
Bloc <- as.data.frame(Bloc)
M <- nrow(Bloc)
#create blankd data.frame
G <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
G[,1:3] <- as.character(G[,1:3])
#G <- data.frame(sdw=character(), sd=character(), ID= character())
colnames(G) <- c("sdw", "sd", "ID")
N <- M
mch <- as.data.frame(Bloc)
#Loop to sequentially fill data.frame
for (i in 1:M) {
  # test if ID already in previous groups
  if(Bloc[i,"ID"] %in% G$ID == FALSE) { 
    # convert element to vector to check for intersect
    tm <- strsplit(x=Bloc[i, "sd"], split=", ")
    mch$t <- numeric(length=M)
  }
  for (j in 1:N){
    #if intersect exists apply code as 1 mch$t column
    ff <- strsplit(x=mch[j, "sd"], split=", ")[[1]]
    dd <- intersect (tm[[1]], ff)
    if (identical(dd, character(0))== FALSE) mch[j,"t"] = 1
  }
  submch <- subset(mch, t == 1 )
  ID <- submch$ID
  Group1 <- sort((unlist(strsplit(paste0(submch$sdw, collapse=","), ","))))
  Group1 <- unique(gsub(" ","", Group1))
  sdw <- rep(paste0(Group1, collapse=", "), nrow(submch))
  Group2 <- sort((unlist(strsplit(paste0(submch$sd, collapse=","), ","))))
  Group2 <- unique(gsub(" ","", Group2))
  sd <- rep(paste0(Group2, collapse=", "), nrow(submch))
  G1 <- cbind(sdw, sd, ID)
  G1 <- unique(G1)
  G <- rbind(G, G1)
  mch$t <- NULL
}

G <- unique(G)
G2 <- data.table(G, key="ID")
G2 <- G2[, list(sdw = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sdw, split=", ")))), collapse=", "), 
                sd = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sd, split=", ")))), collapse=", "))  , by = "ID"]
G2 <- data.table( G2, key=c("sd", "sdw"))
G2 <- unique(G2)
```

#### Get the output as data.table

```
Bloc <- G2[-1,]
Bloc$ID <- NULL
```

#### Repeat the above loop until no more intersects are left

```
repeat
{
  N1 <- nrow(Bloc)
  Bloc <- Bloc[ , list( ID = unlist( strsplit( sd , "," ) ) ) , by = list(sdw, sd) ]
  Bloc$ID <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", Bloc$ID)
  Bloc <- data.table( Bloc , key = "ID" )

  Bloc <- as.data.frame(Bloc)
  M <- nrow(Bloc)
  #create blankd data.frame
  G <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  G[,1:3] <- as.character(G[,1:3])
  #G <- data.frame(sdw=character(), sd=character(), ID= character())
  colnames(G) <- c("sdw", "sd", "ID")
  N <- M
  mch <- as.data.frame(Bloc)
  #Loop to sequentially fill data.frame
  for (i in 1:M) {
    # test if ID already in previous groups
    if(Bloc[i,"ID"] %in% G$ID == FALSE) { 
      # convert element to vector to check for intersect
      tm <- strsplit(x=Bloc[i, "sd"], split=", ")

      mch$t <- numeric(length=M)
    }
    for (j in 1:N){
      #check if intersect exists and code accordingly
      ff <- strsplit(x=mch[j, "sd"], split=", ")[[1]]
      dd <- intersect (tm[[1]], ff)
      if (identical(dd, character(0))== FALSE) mch[j,"t"] = 1
    }
    submch <- subset(mch, t == 1 )
    ID <- submch$ID
    Group1 <- sort((unlist(strsplit(paste0(submch$sdw, collapse=","), ","))))
    Group1 <- unique(gsub(" ","", Group1))
    sdw <- rep(paste0(Group1, collapse=", "), nrow(submch))
    Group2 <- sort((unlist(strsplit(paste0(submch$sd, collapse=","), ","))))
    Group2 <- unique(gsub(" ","", Group2))
    sd <- rep(paste0(Group2, collapse=", "), nrow(submch))
    G1 <- cbind(sdw, sd, ID)
    G1 <- unique(G1)
    G <- rbind(G, G1)
    mch$t <- NULL
  }

  G <- unique(G)
  G2 <- data.table(G, key="ID")

  G2 <- G2[, list(sdw = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sdw, split=", ")))), collapse=", "), 
                  sd = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sd, split=", ")))), collapse=", "))  , by = "ID"]
  G2 <- data.table( G2, key=c("sd", "sdw"))
  G2 <- unique(G2)
  Bloc <- G2[-1,]
  Bloc$ID <- NULL
  N2 <- nrow(Bloc)  
if (N1 == N2)
break
}
```

#### Output

Bloc$sdw

```
[1] "SD1:FIELD, SD1:LUSH, SD23:SWITCH, SD32:TRUMPET, SD384:FR563, SD44:CANCEL, SD567:TREK"                              
[2] "SD12:PAINTING, SD183:WIRE, SD315:MONEY31, SD340:DUST, SD345:FOX, SD345:HOLE, SD387:ROLL, SD387:SPRING, SD42:CRAYON"
[3] "SD39:MATURE, SD455:TOMATO"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of:

```
id <- lapply(d, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), "[", 1))
tbl <- table(unlist(id))
```

to separate out the IDs, and find which ones occur in multiple entries with:

```
repeatIDs <- names(tbl)[tbl>1]
out <- list()
```

Now, build up a compressed list of any that contain the duplicated IDs with:

```
for (i in repeatIDs) {
    ind <- sapply(id, function(x) any(i==x))
    out[[i]] <- paste(unlist(d[ind]), collapse=", ")
}
```

Comment: This is merging the sample data according to SD1, SD32, SD345 and SD387 as they are duplicated in multiple vectors. I want to merge vectors which have an intersection between them. I will try with the tbl table created to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you calculate the `id` in Gavin's answer, and then calculate all the `intersect(id[[j]],id[[k]])` , or maybe even better:

```
for (j in unique(unlist(id))) sapply(id,function(k) j%in%k)
```

will give you the intersections (you'll have to massage the `TRUE TRUE FALSE...` vectors which result from that code)

EDIT:  so here's what to followup with:

```
id <- lapply(sdin, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), "[", 1))
# id is 
# [[1]]
# [1] "SD1"   "SD44"  "SD384" "SD32" 

# [[2]]
# [1] "SD23"  "SD1"   "SD567"

# [[3]]
# [1] "SD42"  "SD345" "SD183"

# [[4]]
# [1] "SD345" "SD340" "SD387"

# [[5]]
# [1] "SD455" "SD39" 

# [[6]]
# [1] "SD12"  "SD315" "SD387"

# [[7]]
# [1] "SD32" "SD1"

idnames<-unique(unlist(id)) 
# [1] "SD1"   "SD44"  "SD384" "SD32"  "SD23"  "SD567" "SD42" 
 # [8] "SD345" "SD183" "SD340" "SD387" "SD455" "SD39"  "SD12" 
# [15] "SD315"

matid<-matrix(NA,nrow=15,ncol=7)
for(k in 1:length(idnames) ) matid[k,] <- unlist(sapply(id, function(j) idnames[k]%in%j))
      # [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
 # [1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 # [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 # [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 # [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 # [5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 # [6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 # [7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 # [8,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 # [9,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [11,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [12,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [13,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [14,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [15,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Each row of that matrix corresponds to one of the "SDx" values, and each column to one of the list elements in your input `d` list.  You should be able to generate your Venn-ish diagrams from that table.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I am not able to go further than creating `id` list by splitting at `:`.