# Merging/Collapsing data.table rows based on common strings

Tags: string, r, data.table, plyr, sqldf

This is a followup to my previous question [Merging vectors of strings in a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387917/merging-vectors-of-strings-in-a-list-in-r/23406960?noredirect=1#23406960)

I have tried an alternate approach using `data.table`.

I have a `data.table` G as follows

```
d <- list( c("SD1:LUSH", "SD44:CANCEL", "SD384:FR563", "SD32:TRUMPET"), c("SD23:SWITCH", "SD1:LUSH", "SD567:TREK"), c("SD42:CRAYON", "SD345:FOX", "SD183:WIRE"), c("SD345:HOLE", "SD340:DUST", "SD387:ROLL"), c("SD455:TOMATO", "SD39:MATURE"), c("SD12:PAINTING", "SD315:MONEY31", "SD387:SPRING"),  c("SD32:TRUMPET", "SD1:FIELD"))
d2 <-  lapply(d, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), "[", 1))

d <- lapply(d, paste0, collapse=", ")
d2 <- lapply(d2, paste0, collapse=", ")

d <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(lapply(d, paste0, collapse=", ")))
d2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(lapply(d2, paste0, collapse=", ")))

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(d,d2))
colnames(d) <- c("sdw", "sd")
d$sd <- as.character(d$sd)
d$sdw <- as.character(d$sdw)



 G <- data.table( d , key = "sd" )
                                                sdw                     sd
1: SD1:LUSH, SD44:CANCEL, SD384:FR563, SD32:TRUMPET SD1, SD44, SD384, SD32
2:       SD12:PAINTING, SD315:MONEY31, SD387:SPRING     SD12, SD315, SD387
3:                SD23:SWITCH, SD1:LUSH, SD567:TREK       SD23, SD1, SD567
4:                          SD32:TRUMPET, SD1:FIELD              SD32, SD1
5:               SD345:HOLE, SD340:DUST, SD387:ROLL    SD345, SD340, SD387
6:               SD42:CRAYON, SD345:FOX, SD183:WIRE     SD42, SD345, SD183
7:                        SD455:TOMATO, SD39:MATURE            SD455, SD39
```

I am trying to aggregate elements in column sdw based on elements in column sd.

[1], [2] and [7] have **SD1** common between them. So their corresponding sdw elements should merge together. Also [1] and [7] have both **SD1** and **SD32** common.

[4] has **SD345** common with [3] and **SD387** common with [5]. So [4], [3] and [5] sdw elements should merge together.

[7] is not having any **SD__** common with other vectors, so it should remain as such.

In short I want to aggregate G$sdw elements based on overlapping **SD__** terms in G$sd

The output I am looking for is as follows with just three rows.

```
[1] "SD1:LUSH, SD1:FIELD,  SD23:SWITCH, SD32:TRUMPET, SD44:CANCEL, SD384:FR563,  SD567:TREK"            
[2] "SD12:PAINTING, SD42:CRAYON, SD183:WIRE, SD340:DUST SD345:FOX, SD345:HOLE, SD387:SPRING, SD387:ROLL"
[3] "SD455:TOMATO, SD39:MATURE"
```

I have tried `data.table` package as follows

```
# Extract SDs from GN$sd
G <- G[ , list( ID = unlist( strsplit( sd , "," ) ) ) , by = list(sdw, sd) ]
G$ID <- gsub(" ", "", G$ID)
G <- data.table( G , key = "ID" )

# Merge according to common IDs
G2 <- G[, list(Gp1 = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sdw, split=", ")))), collapse=", "),
                           Gp2 = paste0(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(sd, split=", ")))), collapse=", "))  , by = "ID"]

G2 <- data.table( G, key="Gp2")
G2 <- unique(G2)
G2

ID                                                                                  Gp1                                 Gp2
1:   SD1 SD1:FIELD, SD1:LUSH, SD23:SWITCH, SD32:TRUMPET, SD384:FR563, SD44:CANCEL, SD567:TREK SD1, SD23, SD32, SD384, SD44, SD567
2:  SD23                                                    SD1:LUSH, SD23:SWITCH, SD567:TREK                    SD1, SD23, SD567
3:  SD32                          SD1:FIELD, SD1:LUSH, SD32:TRUMPET, SD384:FR563, SD44:CANCEL              SD1, SD32, SD384, SD44
4: SD387       SD12:PAINTING, SD315:MONEY31, SD340:DUST, SD345:HOLE, SD387:ROLL, SD387:SPRING    SD12, SD315, SD340, SD345, SD387
5:  SD12                                           SD12:PAINTING, SD315:MONEY31, SD387:SPRING                  SD12, SD315, SD387
6: SD345               SD183:WIRE, SD340:DUST, SD345:FOX, SD345:HOLE, SD387:ROLL, SD42:CRAYON    SD183, SD340, SD345, SD387, SD42
7: SD183                                                   SD183:WIRE, SD345:FOX, SD42:CRAYON                  SD183, SD345, SD42
8: SD340                                                   SD340:DUST, SD345:HOLE, SD387:ROLL                 SD340, SD345, SD387
9:  SD39                                                            SD39:MATURE, SD455:TOMATO                         SD39, SD455
```

This can only merge based on duplication of **SD__** terms across rows in G$sd. It is not taking into consideration multiple common terms across elements and also same element having distinct common terms with other elements.

Is there any way to achieve the desired output in `R`. My full dataset has thousands of such rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two dataframes containing duplicate elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798095/merge-two-dataframes-containing-duplicate-elements)