# Merge two dataframes containing duplicate elements

Tags: r, merge

Given two dataframes whose names overlap partially, `foo` and `bar`:

```
foo <- iris[1:10,-c(4,5)]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1           5.1         3.5          1.4
# 2           4.9         3.0          1.4
# 3           4.7         3.2          1.3
# 4           4.6         3.1          1.5
# 5           5.0         3.6          1.4
# 6           5.4         3.9          1.7
# 7           4.6         3.4          1.4
# 8           5.0         3.4          1.5
# 9           4.4         2.9          1.4
# 10          4.9         3.1          1.5

bar <- iris[3:13,-c(3,5)]
bar[1:8, ] <- bar[1:8, ] * 2
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Width
# 3           9.4         6.4         0.4
# 4           9.2         6.2         0.4
# 5          10.0         7.2         0.4
# 6          10.8         7.8         0.8
# 7           9.2         6.8         0.6
# 8          10.0         6.8         0.4
# 9           8.8         5.8         0.4
# 10          9.8         6.2         0.2
# 11          5.4         3.7         0.2
# 12          4.8         3.4         0.2
# 13          4.8         3.0         0.1
```

How can I merge the dataframes such that both rows and columns are padded for missing cases, while prioritising the results of one dataframe for overlapping elements? In this example, it is the overlapping results in `bar` that I wish to prioritise.

`merge(..., by = "row.names", all = TRUE)` is close, in that it retains all 13 rows, and returns missing values as NA:

```
foobar <- merge(foo, bar, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)
#    Row.names Sepal.Length.x Sepal.Width.x Petal.Length Sepal.Length.y Sepal.Width.y Petal.Width
# 1          1            5.1           3.5          1.4             NA            NA          NA
# 2         10            4.9           3.1          1.5            9.8           6.2         0.2
# 3         11             NA            NA           NA            5.4           3.7         0.2
# 4         12             NA            NA           NA            4.8           3.4         0.2
# 5         13             NA            NA           NA            4.8           3.0         0.1
# 6          2            4.9           3.0          1.4             NA            NA          NA
# 7          3            4.7           3.2          1.3            9.4           6.4         0.4
# 8          4            4.6           3.1          1.5            9.2           6.2         0.4
# 9          5            5.0           3.6          1.4           10.0           7.2         0.4
# 10         6            5.4           3.9          1.7           10.8           7.8         0.8
# 11         7            4.6           3.4          1.4            9.2           6.8         0.6
# 12         8            5.0           3.4          1.5           10.0           6.8         0.4
# 13         9            4.4           2.9          1.4            8.8           5.8         0.4
```

However, it creates a distinct column for each column in the constituent dataframes, regardless of the fact that they share names.

The desired output would be as such:

```
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1           5.1         3.5          1.4          NA # unique to foo
# 2           4.9         3.0          1.4          NA # unique to foo
# 3           9.4         6.4          1.3          0.4 # overlap, retained from bar
# 4           9.2         6.2          1.5          0.4 # 
# 5          10.0         7.2          1.4          0.4 # .
# 6          10.8         7.8          1.7          0.8 # .
# 7           9.2         6.8          1.4          0.6 # .
# 8          10.0         6.8          1.5          0.4 # 
# 9           8.8         5.8          1.4          0.4 # 
# 10          9.8         6.2          1.5          0.2 # overlap, retained from bar
# 11          5.4         3.7           NA          0.2 # unique to bar
# 12          4.8         3.4           NA          0.2 # unique to bar
# 13          4.8         3.0           NA          0.1 # unique to bar
```

My intuition is to subset the data into two disjoint sets, and the set of intersecting elements in `bar`, then merge these, but I'm sure there is a more elegant solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited)
The package plyr is awesome for this sort of thing. Just do:

```
 library(plyr)
 foo$ID <- row.names(foo)
 bar$ID <- row.names(bar)
 foobar <- join(foo, bar, type = "full", by = "ID")
```

Joining by row.names didn't work, as Flodl noted in the comments, so that's why I made a new column "ID".

Comment: `Error in `[.data.frame`(x, by) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: Furthermore, the help page suggests that we should expect the result to be the same as from `merge`.

Comment: Now this is not doing the overwriting like the OP wants. Please test and compare with his expected output.

Comment: Ah, I see... Yes, I think any solution I would have wouldn't be any better than the one voidHead is thinking of.

Comment: `join(bar, foo, type = "full", by = "ID", match = "first")` seems more like it. If the OP does not care for the order of the rows and columns.

Comment: @flodel You're right, swapping order of the parameters gives (something very close to) the expected output. Re-ordering rows and columns is a concession I can make.

Answer (score 1):

I see the glowing recommendation for `plyr::join` but do not see how it is much different than what the base `merge` offers:

```
 merge(foo, bar, by=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), all=TRUE)
```

Comment: Well, it is clearly not what the OP wants. Just compare your output with the OP's.

Comment: Agreed not clear. I assumed that the difference in the Petal.Width values were explained by laziness on the part of the OP. The missing calculated text values are explained by laziness on my part.

Comment: @BondedDust Which Petal.Width values are you referring to? I constructed the expected output by hand, but I believe it's consistent with the example data.

Comment: All those Petal.Length values less than 1.0. There are none such in the original.

Comment: Right you are. Corrected.